# Why can't a generic struct type be inferred by the argument it is initialized with?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm not sure if I can describe this problem clearly enough but have managed to product a small (enough) reproducible example. In this code I create a generic struct with protocol-constrained extensions for an entity from source A, and an entity from source B. The method in the correct extension is called.

```
protocol Entity { }

protocol FromSource_A: Entity { }
protocol FromSource_B: Entity { }

struct Apple: FromSource_A { }
struct Orange: FromSource_B { }

protocol StructProtocol {
    func go ()
}

struct MyStruct<T: Entity>: StructProtocol {
    func go () {
        print("MyStruct default go()")
    }
}

extension MyStruct where T : FromSource_A {
    func go () {
        print("MyStruct extension where T : FromSource_A")
    }
}

extension MyStruct where T : FromSource_B {
    func go () {
        print("MyStruct extension where T : FromSource_B")
    }
}

let myStruct = MyStruct<Apple>()
myStruct.go() // <- Output: "MyStruct extension where T : FromSource_A"
```

Now, when I add a property to `MyStruct` that is also generic, and initialize a concrete instance of it with a `GenericArgument` passed to it, I hope that the concrete type `GenericArgument<Apple>` will inform the generic `MyStruct` what `T` is, and allow the correct extension to be called on `MyStruct`.

```
....

struct MyStruct<T: Entity>: StructProtocol {
    var genericArgument: GenericArgument<T> // Adding generic argument that takes T from MyStruct declaration

    func go () {
        print("MyStruct default go()")
    }
}

extension MyStruct where T : FromSource_A {
    func go () {
        print("MyStruct extension where T : FromSource_A")
    }
}

extension MyStruct where T : FromSource_B {
    func go () {
        print("MyStruct extension where T : FromSource_B")
    }
}

/// Now introduce passing type between structs

struct GenericArgument<T: Entity> { }

func test<T: Entity> (argument: GenericArgument<T>) {
    let myStruct = MyStruct<T>(genericArgument: argument)
    myStruct.go()
}

let genericArgument = GenericArgument<Apple>()

test(argument: genericArgument) // <- Output: "MyStruct default go()"
```

Instead the default method implementation of `MyStruct` is called.

As far as I can see, the problem arises when I introduce another layer to pass the generic information through (`func test<T: Entity> (argument: GenericArgument<T>) {}`) where given a concrete argument, the receiver can't figure out what it's generic type has been filled in with.

Why doesn't `MyStruct` call the method in the correct extension when it's type is inferred by the argument it is initialized with?

Comment: Extension members aren't dynamically dispatched. Generics are resolved at compile time. All the compiler knows is that `myStruct` is generic over `T`, for any possible `T`, so iIt picks the default implementation of `go`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be trying to create class inheritance out of generics. That's not possible. Generics are not dynamically dispatched. That's on purpose and allows a lot more optimizations.

Providing specialized extension over a default implementation using `where` clauses like you've done here should only be done for performance improvements. If the compiler can prove something about the types (it's a bidirectional collection rather than a sequence for example), then it can be useful to provide a more efficient algorithm to produce the same output. But all calls to `MyStruct.go()` should have the same semantics (produce the same output). The decision on what version of `go` to call is made at *compile* time based only on information available at compile time. It's possible that `test()` would be called from some other part of the program with a different type, so the function can't be specialized to apply the right `where` clause. It has to assume the most general case allowed.

In this specific case, what would you expect to happen if I added the following line:

```
extension Apple: FromSource_B {}
```

That's completely legal since `Apple` conforms to `FromSource_B`. I could even add this line of code in another module (after everything here has been compiled). So what code should run? This is pointing to a design mistake.

Instead of trying to recreate class-inheritance overriding, what you probably want here is to attach behavior to the Entity types. For example:

```
// Entities have a way to go()
protocol Entity {
    static func go()
}

// And if they don't provide one, there's a default
extension Entity {
    static func go() {
        print("MyStruct default go()")
    }
}

// FromSource_A and _B provide their own default ways to conform

protocol FromSource_A: Entity { }
protocol FromSource_B: Entity { }

extension FromSource_A {
    static func go() {
        print("MyStruct extension where T : FromSource_A")
    }
}

extension FromSource_B {
    static func go() {
        print("MyStruct extension where T : FromSource_B")
    }
}

// Apple and Orange conform, and take the default behaviors (they could provide their own)
struct Apple: FromSource_A { }
struct Orange: FromSource_B { }

// MyStruct (there's no need for a protocol) accepts a GenericArgument, but
// only to nail down what `T` is.
struct GenericArgument<T: Entity> { }

struct MyStruct<T: Entity> {
    var genericArgument: GenericArgument<T>

    func go () {
        T.go()
    }
}

// And the rest
func test<T: Entity> (argument: GenericArgument<T>) {
    let myStruct = MyStruct<T>(genericArgument: argument)
    myStruct.go()
}

let genericArgument = GenericArgument<Apple>()

test(argument: genericArgument)  // MyStruct extension where T : FromSource_A
```

You still need to be a little careful with this. There are cases where it could break. For example, what if someone writes this code in another module:

```
extension Apple {
    static func go() { print("This is an Apple.") }
}
```

This might or might not behave as you expect. I'd work hard to get rid of all the generics, and almost all the protocols, and do it this way with simple structs and trivial protocols:

```
protocol Entity {}

protocol Source {
    func go()
    func makeEntity() -> Entity
}

struct Apple: Entity { }
struct Orange: Entity { }

struct Source_A: Source {
    func go() { print("From A") }
    func makeEntity() -> Entity { return Apple() }
}

struct Source_B: Source {
    func go() { print("From B") }
    func makeEntity() -> Entity { return Orange() }

}

struct GenericArgument {
    let source: Source
}

struct MyStruct {
    var genericArgument: GenericArgument

    func go () {
        genericArgument.source.go()
    }
}

func test(argument: GenericArgument) {
    let myStruct = MyStruct(genericArgument: argument)
    myStruct.go()
}

let genericArgument = GenericArgument(source: Source_A())

test(argument: genericArgument)
```

It's possible your problem actually needs generics here, but you should start with writing out the code as simply as possible (including allowing it to duplicate), and then look for how to remove that duplication with generics. You should not jump to generics too quickly; most of us will choose the wrong abstraction.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, as well as the guidance!